# Trigger on update

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I would like to define a trigger to set a column ( deleted_at ) at ' NOW() ' when a row is modified. I tried things like this =>

```
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE articles SET updated_at = NOW() ;
END;
```

But i have errors like this =>

> #1064 - Syntax error near '' line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you remove `BEGIN` and `END` (if you have only one statement in your trigger) or you put a different delimiter. Also you don't do an update in an update trigger. Make it a `BEFORE` trigger and set the value directly.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.updated_at = NOW() ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok, thanx, i understand, NEW is the line line inserted. And if i want do activ the trigger when I update a line ??

Comment: `NEW` is the value you provided in your insert statement or the value it should have afterwards, `OLD` is the value before the statement did anything. If you want to have a trigger for an update statement, you have to write another trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you're updating your table in the trigger itself.

Why don't you use a before insert trigger like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    set NEW.updated_at = NOW() ;
END;
```

That way you are sure your field is updated in every insert.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the line

```
 UPDATE articles SET updated_at = NOW() ;
```

with this one

```
 SET NEW.updated_at = NOW() ;
```